# Does Community ♦ downvote VLQ posts?

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts, community-user

Flagging a post as spam/offensive makes [the Community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) downvote that post.

Does the same thing happen with the "very low quality" flag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Community user downvotes a post with no upvotes if a moderator marks a VLQ flag helpful ([example](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/72257/325), requires 10k on Workplace). (I was puzzled the first time I saw this happen.) Community does not vote just because a flag is raised, unlike with spam.  It appears that the automatic downvote doesn't happen if a VLQ flag is validated through the review queue ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13163573)).

It's rare for a helpful VLQ flag to not end in deletion (at which point the vote doesn't really matter any more), but it happens.

Comment: Are you sure this is still happening? The flag is marked helpful as soon as the first reviewer recommends deletion of the post, and I personally have never seen this happen. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13163573) is an example of a deleted post with score 0; [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/13163570) is another one which is not yet deleted, but at least one person did already.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if it requires that mod action validates the flag?  I can't see deleted SO posts; can you confirm that there are no upvotes there?  It's votes, not net score,  that matters. (I'll see if I can test later when not using SE on a phone. )

Comment: No votes at all on these posts: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ABwMM.png http://i.stack.imgur.com/3435v.png

Comment: I just tested this on [this post](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/72257/325), which was +0/-2 with a VLQ flag.  I validated the flag (through the flag interface) and the post went to -3.  (I'll come back and delete it later, after we're done with science.)

Comment: OK, it could be very well different for moderators validating a flag. I'm just a mere mortal with a bunch of rep points :)

Comment: Thanks for the science.  I've edited.

Comment: The down vote probably counts towards an answer ban after it's deleted however, so I think it does matter, at least a little.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. Try for yourself; it shouldn't be hard (on Stack Overflow) to find a post which warrants a Low Quality flag. Flagging won't change the post score.